# Receiving zero products for in app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, sandbox

I have created a consumable in app purchase in iTunes connect as shown in the following figure.

[image]

After that I created a sandbox user and I verified that appid.

When I try to check the products using the following code

```
func requestProducts(forIds ids: Set<String>)
{
    productRequest.cancel()
    productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: "com.iapcourse.meal")
    productRequest.delegate = self
    productRequest.start()
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    self.products = response.products
    print(products.count)
    if products.count == 0
    {
        requestProducts(forIds: "com.iapcourse.meal")
    }
    else {
        delegate?.iapProductsLoaded()
    }
}
```

I receive zero product from the delegate method.

Comment: Metadata is missing, first complete its data.

Comment: It is not Working

Comment: Make sure you logged in xcode with same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status of your in-app purchases needs to be in the "Ready to Submit" stage before you can test in Sandbox. A common thing to miss is the preview image, for testing, you can upload anything you want so the meta-data is complete. Also, you need to make sure you have the "Paid Applications" agreement signed - it's not very clear anywhere in App Store connect that this is required so it's sometimes overlooked.

I really good article that goes over a checklist of everything you need to configure is: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)

Comment: actually what is I was missing is the Paid Applications Agreement signing

Answer (score 0):

From what I discovered, MetaData is not important. The important issue is to sign user agreements and tax forums